# Outer join providing inner join results

Tags: mysql

This should be a very simple solution, which means you'll probably think this is a dumb question, but I've tried everything I can think of.

I have two tables, one for possible poll choices, and the other for actual responses. They're structured like so:

```
choices         responses
-----------     ----------
poll_id         poll_id
choice_id       user_id
choice_text     choice_id
```

I have a poll with two choices (yes/no), so I'm trying to fetch results so that if no one has voted for a certain choice, that choice shows up in the result set with a `null` value. So if 3 users have voted "yes" and none have voted "no", I want the result set to be:

```
choice_text      num
-----------------------------
yes              3
no               null
```

I would have thought this simply an outer join like so:

```
select
    c.choice_text,
    count(*) num
from
    choices c
        left outer join responses r
            on c.poll_id = r.poll_id
            and c.choice_id = r.choice_id
where
    r.poll_id = 1
group by r.choice_id
order by r.choice_id asc;
```

But alas, that is giving me:

```
choice_text      num
-----------------------------
yes              3
```

...without any record for "no".

I've tried every language for joins I can think of, with the same erroneous result.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your where condition on the outer joined table turns the outer join into an inner join. Move that condition into the `JOIN`

```
select c.choice_text,
       count(*) num
from choices c
   left outer join responses r
          on c.poll_id = r.poll_id
         and c.choice_id = r.choice_id
         and r.poll_id = 1
group by r.choice_id
order by r.choice_id asc;
```

Btw: your usage of `group by` is incorrect and every other DBMS would reject that statement. MySQL simply chooses to return random data instead of failing with an error. For more details please see these blogs:

- [Debunking GROUP BY myths](http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html)
- [Wrong GROUP BY makes your queries fragile](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/)

Comment: That query resulted in the same result set (no "no" record shows up).

Comment: @praguian: I wouldn't be suprised if that was due to the illegal `group by`usage. Can you create a SQLFiddle example? http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name pointing me in the right direction.

The winning query:

```
select c.choice_text,
       count(r.user_id) num
from choices c
   left outer join responses r
         on c.poll_id = r.poll_id
         and c.choice_id = r.choice_id
         and c.poll_id = 1
group by c.choice_id
order by c.choice_id asc;
```

Moved the c.poll_id clause to the join, like @a_horse_with_no_name suggested, but then had to group by the choices table instead of the responses table, and finally changed my `count(*)` to `count(r.user_id)`, and voila.